# Notepad++'s Compare plugin algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, notepad++, string-comparison

I need to create a tool in C#.Net that have the exactly same functions like Notepad++ Compare plugin, do you have any idea how can I do this?

Right now I am using this algo:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6943/A-Generic-Reusable-Diff-Algorithm-in-C-II

But my client wants to highlight the difference like in the Notepad++ Compare plugin.

Thanks for any idea!

-JRC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not find the exact algorithm ready to serve. But what you can do is, you can easily customize the logic of [A Generic, Reusable Diff Algorithm in C# - II](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6943/A-Generic-Reusable-Diff-Algorithm-in-C-II), by replacing the `Line` column with image column, showing the *Addition* and *Deletion* image as `Notepad++` do at the time of comparison.

OR

You can also have a look at this [Diff.NET](http://www.menees.com/index.html), which might be useful.

*Screenshots:*

1. [File Difference](http://www.menees.com/Images/FileDiffScreen.jpg)
2. [Directory Difference](http://www.menees.com/Images/FileDiffScreen.jpg)

Comment: thanks for this FSX! I will customize the Diff.NET for my needs. Thanks so much! You save my day!

Answer (score 2):

I used it in one of my projects: http://diffplex.codeplex.com/